Imwrite OPEN CV method
I have a simple question about OpenCV imwrite method. Which is the difference between doing that:
cv2.imwrite("route", cv2.cvtColor(image*255, cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR))

and this
cv2.imwrite("route", image*255)

I think that both should do the same, because OpenCV treats images as BGR, but when I visualize my image, they are different. Why?

They're different because cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR reverses the color channels.

Yeah but, imwrite writes the image to disk as RGB, so I don't urdestand why both methods are not equal.

No, imwrite writes to disk according to the channel order of the array. It has no way of knowing whether those channels represent RGB, BGR, HSV, LUV, XYZ or ABC. By passing an array to imwrite you are telling it "what I am passing you is in BGR order." If you lie to it, it will never know.

Ok, I think I have just understood you. You are saying that, if I have a numpy array with 3 matrix, if I save it with no conversion, third matrix is R, second G and first B, because imwrite expect BGR, but, if I convert it, first matrix is R, second G and third B. It's ok?

It should be like this extension cv2.imwrite("route.jpg", ...)

You have to pass a BGR or grayscale image to imwrite. If your image is in a different color space (or the RGB channels are in a different order than BGR), you need to convert the image to BGR to save it with imwrite.
So, the first line of code assumes that the channels are in RGB order, the call to cv2.cvtColor(..., cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR) puts them in BGR order. The second line of code assumes that the channels are in BGR order, and saves them as such.

So, the main thing is that for example, if I want to save a certain array in the same order as I have it, I have to convert to BGR (reverse it) in order to imwrite saving it as I wanted.

@David "save in same order as I have it" is ambiguous. If you use OpenCV imread to read the file later, then don't change order. imread will return the same array that you put into imwrite. If you read it in another application, and you have an RGB image, then you need to reverse the order of the channels for OpenCV to do the right thing.

@David I recommend that you use the imageio package to read and write image data, rather than OpenCV, unless all your processing, and all your input and output is done in OpenCV. If you get your image through some other package, use imageio to save it. Then you won't have to worry about OpenCV's wonky RGB channel order.

@DavidMuñoz if you have a 3-channel-matrix and use cv2.imwrite to create an image from it, the first channel of the matrix will become the blue color channel and the third channel of the matrix will become the red color channel.  That's all you need to know about cv2.imwrite. If you dont know what ordering your initial matrix has, read the docs of what has generated the matrix.

When reading the image using cv2.imread, cv2 internally converts a RGB image to BGR. Similarly, when using cv2.imwrite, cv2 internally converts a BGR image to RGB while storing.
So for your example:
cv2.imwrite("route", cv2.cvtColor(image*255, cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR)) assumes that image is in RGB and it needs to be converted to BGR before using the cv2.imwrite or else the red channel and blue channel will get inverted (which I guess is happening for you).

cv2.imwrite("route", image*255) assumes that the image is in BGR format and thus storing it using c2.imwrite save it with the channels in RGB order.

Thus, they're not doing the same thing.

Ref: https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/d4/da8/group__imgcodecs.html

OpenCV doesn't really convert  RGB to BGR. It just normally puts the RGB channels in inverse order from what we're used to. BGR is not a different color space, it's still an RGB image. OpenCV made a wonky choice initially, and they coined "BGR" to deal with the repercussions of that choice.

Thanks, I think it works like that: if I have a numpy array with 3 matrix, if I save it with no conversion, third matrix is R, second G and first B, because imwrite expect BGR, but, if I convert it, first matrix is R, second G and third B. –

"c2.imwrite save it with the channels in RGB order" this might be misleading. It depends on the actual image data file format, how the images are saved. BUT imwrite will save it according to that image file format. So any image application can read it in the "right" channel ordering.

Assuming image is of dtype np.uint8, and contains values from 0 to 255 (not 0.0 to 1.0)... your expression image * 255 accidentally is equivalent to a negation/subtraction.
>>> np.uint8([0, 1, ..., 254, 255]) * 255
array([  0, 255, ...,   2,   1], dtype=uint8)


of course, if you swap the color channels around, the result will look even funkier.


but when I visualize my image, they are different. Why?

Original image:

With cv2.cvtColor
Screenshot:

Without cv2.Color:
Screenshot:

